# Is there a difference between "entrenched" and "ensconced"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

Source: Lexicon Dictionary

Definitions:

> 1. entrenched: firmly or solidly established; placed in a position of strength

> 2. ensconced: establish or settle (someone) in a comfortable, safe, or secret place:

Examples:

> 1. Ensconced:
>
> "Agnes ensconced herself in their bedroom

> 2. Entrenched:
>
> "an entrenched resistance to change"

The only similarity I see between these two words is the idea of "being firmly established within a position".

Comment: The word "entrenched" brings associations of trench warfare and other unpleasant things. While "ensconced" has fewer connotations (and if people have heard the word "sconce" it's probably for a thing for holding a candle or lamp, rather than anything relevant to this usage).

Answer (score 1):

**Ensconced** almost always refers to a location. For example, you can be ensconced in your home, in a hotel, in a corner, etc.

**Entrenched** can be more figurative. You can use it to describe a belief or an attitude, where you cannot do that with ensconced.

At least in American English, it would be unusual to hear someone use the word ensconced. An ordinary American would probably have to look it up.

Comment: Are you sure about an American needing to look it up.? It is widely used in the UK - *It's no good trying to chat with John, he's ensconced in a corner of the sitting room reading the newspaper".

Comment: I'm sure. I don't think I would ever hear that in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that ***entrench*** is mostly used metaphorically - representing resistance to change or forward (or backward) movement.

***Ensconse*** per the OED is mostly concerned with concealment, but as sense 3b points out it nowadays has a lot to do with a feeling of:

> 3b. of security, comfort, ‘snugness’, etc. Chiefly reflexive.
> e.g.
> 1841   C. Dickens Old Curiosity Shop i. xviii. 189   Ensconcing
> themselves..in the warm chimney-corner.

Answer (score 0):

Both have a military origin. We know about *trenches* from the First World War, of course, but Oxford's secondary definition of *sconce* is - (Archaic) *a small fort or earthwork defending a ford, pass, or castle gate*.

*Entrenched* describes a fixed opinion which you are determined to defend.

*Ensconced*, which originally had the sense 'safely concealed within a fortification', has come to mean 'settled in a safe place'.